# MVC - notifying all users in the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

What i need to do is a simple char applicaiton(I know there are many).

My restrication is that i need to use mvc and reactJs only(assignment).

My missing link is simply how can i notify all the users of the app of an event?

For ex: one user clicked login, i want to send an event to all users that he logged in.

I saw socket.io:

```
socket.on('init', this._initialize);
socket.on('send:message', this._messageRecieve);
```

Also saw signalR but as i said, cant use them as my restrications.

Please tell me if more info is needed.

Comment: this has been addressed on this site a lot of times.  react components should subscribe and publish javascript events to take action if an event message is received.  that way one component can publish an event and another component will listen for that event to occur and take action if it does.

Comment: Why can't you use SignalR?  You could have SignalR broadcast a message to all clients, where the SignalR JS client would dispatch a Login Action in react/flux, which in turn would update your relevant store and thus the components that are subscribed to the store.